# Как отсортировать массив из объектов по двум свойствам?

Tags: javascript

Есть не сортированный массив, который нужно отсортировать по принципу **если value текущего элемента равно val следующего** то в начале идет текущий элемент, затем следующий элемент удовлетворяющий данному условию, проход массива начинается с  элемента со значением `val: one`;

Достаточно долго бьюсь с данной задачей и хотелось бы уже узнать, можно ли решить данную задачу с помощью `reduce` или `filter`

```
[
  {val: 'one', value: 'two', someVal: 222},
  {val: 'three', value: 'four', someVal: 26346},
  {val: 'two', value: 'three', someVal: 7565},
  {val: 'six', value: 'one', someVal: 227745}
]
```

На выходе должен получиться такой результат:

```
[
  {val: 'one', value: 'two', someVal: 222},
  {val: 'two', value: 'three', someVal: 7565},
  {val: 'three', value: 'four', someVal: 26346},
  {val: 'six', value: 'one', someVal: 227745}
]
```

Comment: "с начало" - это что, заразно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter ничего сортировать не будет. Он что-то оставит, а что-то 'удалит' из исходного массива. 
Наверное проще все же использовать предназначенный для этого sort

```js
console.log([
    {val: 'one', value: 'two', someVal: 222},
    {val: 'three', value: 'four', someVal: 26346},
    {val: 'two', value: 'three', someVal: 7565},
    {val: 'six', value: 'one', someVal: 227745}
].sort((a,b)=>a.val===b.value));
```